# converting maven project to multimodule

Tags: java, maven

I am separating modules from my existing maven project. So created a core part and a module having all the mybaties interfaces and config files.

So I created my main pom.xml as

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>app</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>app-mybatis</module>
</modules>
```

my core pom.xml is

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>core</name>
<description>my app</description>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!--Joda time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql connector -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--apache common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>   


</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Codehaus</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <finalName>mycom.myproject.net</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>              
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/app</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my mybaties module pom.xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>app-mybatis</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>app-mybatis</name>

<dependencies>

    <!-- mybaties -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

But when I am building mybatis module it gives me an error

```
   package com.mycom.myproject.service.impl.bean does not exist
```

Which is already there in my core module. is there something I am missing in mapping of poms.

Please let me know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The parent in your `mybatis` module is pointing to `app`, so it will not inherit the dependency from `core`. If you have common dependency, then you can create one more module `base` for that, and add it to list of modules in your main pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>base</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>app-mybatis</module>
</modules>
```

`base` pom should hold the common dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
    <artifactId>base</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>my app</description>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- so on -->
    <depedencies>
</project>
```

And now, make this the parent of both the `core` and `app-mybatis`. I guess that should work.

Comment: Hi @Rohit thanks for your prompt response but core is a module not parent here app is parent. I should put <parent> tag inside core pom and I did that but that also does not make any differnec. Still I am getting same error

Comment: @user965884 If `core` is not a parent of `app`, then you need to add dependency in `app` too. How will it inherit the dependency from `core`? Or either make a common base pom for both of them, and define common dependency there. And make that parent of both `core` and `app`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion too and its giving me error    [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

Comment: I created 'app' as parent and define both the module inside that. Please check my first pom.xml. I have shown three poms here one is app, 2nd is core and 3rd is app-mybatis. Does that make any sense please let me know

Comment: @user965884 I guess you can create another module, named `parent`. And define dependency there. And make `parent`, the parent of both `mybatis` and `core`. Basically, you want to use same dependency in `core` and `mybatis`. If that is the case, you should define common dependency in `parent`. Or make `core` the parent of `mybatis`. These are the two options I think you have.

Comment: And if you define `parent` module, the make `app` its parent.

Comment: sorry @Rohit I am not getting you. Could you please give me an example.Thanks

Comment: you mean I add app-mybatis as module inside core? I am just trying to understand what you said

Comment: @user965884 I updated the answer. You can also try going through http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html.

Comment: @user965884 Or rather, a better way would be to move common dependency into the `app` itself, if you don't want to include another module.